# How to resolve security warning concerning WebAdministrationProvider?

Tags: security, iis, wmi, local-system

I have a new Windows Server 2012 install, and have just installed IIS.  I see the following warning in the Application Log:

> A provider, WebAdministrationProvider, has been registered 
>   in the Windows Management Instrumentation namespace 
>   Root\WebAdministration to use the LocalSystem account. This 
>   account is privileged and the provider may cause a security 
>   violation if it does not correctly impersonate user requests.

The source is "WMI," and the event ID is 63.

According to [this TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315566%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), I am supposed to *"Obtain a version of the provider that does not run under the LocalSystem security context."*

I can barely understand the warning and the article.  What does this mean?  If I can't get rid of the provider, can I disable or unregister it?